# Azure Api management find user associated with ocp-apim-subscription-key subscription key

Tags: azure-api-management

Azure has build in authentication is there anyway to check the user associated with ocp-apim-subscription-key programmatically

Comment: ​This is already an open issue at [get ocp_apim_subscription_key programmatically](https://github.com/Azure/api-management-samples/issues/30). 

You can refer to [How to get the User from the subscription-key using Azure API Management REST API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25388105/how-to-get-the-user-from-the-subscription-key-using-azure-api-management-rest-ap)

Answer (score 0):

Inside APIM policy? User object is in the context, you can access it like that:

`context.User`

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-policy-expressions#ref-context-user)