# Azure apim depreciated developer portal

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

When in azure developer portal (depreciated)

We were able to see all the subscriptions for an api (admin view) .Is this also not available in the new portal ?

Is there any API that can provide this information so that we can build this function by ourselves

attaching image for reference

[image]

Comment: You can refer to [Azure API Management REST API reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/),  [How to get the User from the subscription-key using Azure API Management REST API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25388105/how-to-get-the-user-from-the-subscription-key-using-azure-api-management-rest-ap) and [Subscriptions are not displaying in the profile page if the user has a subscription with "ALL APIs" scope](https://github.com/Azure/api-management-developer-portal/issues/894)

Answer (score 0):

***API-scoped*** and ***all-APIs subscriptions*** can be created by **service administrators** and ***users*** can create only ***Product subscriptions***.

If you're using an API-scoped subscription or the all-access subscription, any [policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-policies) configured at the product scope aren't applied to that subscription.

You can get 'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key' by navigating to 'Subscriptions' under your APIM resource or navigating to the API while performing the test.

Click on Subscription --> Select 'Build-in all-access subscription' (Default) or any of the subscription for which you want to test your specific API --> Click on Show/hide keys

[image]

Click on APIs --> Select any of the API's --> Select Any operation --> You can select the Product Scope (Optional) --> Click on Show Icon

[image]

Please Refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-subscriptions) for more information.